# Is there anyway to get the name/label of a field without doing a field describe?

Tags: apex, describesobject

I want to get the name and label of all the fields for multiple sobjects in one transaction and that will easily hit the governor limits. Is there anyway I can get the label/name without using a describe for each field? A mass describe for fields?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your requirements? Do you need ALL fields on ALL objects at once? Or can the user choose an object then interrogate its fields?

Comment: Are we talking about a pure Apex situation, or are you talking about something involving Visualforce?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but the limits around field describes are probobly much more generous than you think. You're allowed up to 100 static compile-time field references (e.g. `Schema.SobjectType.Contact.fields.name.label`).

The limits for dynamic describes are even more generous in most situations, and can be combined with this compile-time format for more flexibility. Quoting a very related answer of mine:

> The limits on describes are very confusingly written, you're not
>   actually limited to 100 calls to Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe(),
>   instead you're limited to 100 calls to
>   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().
>
> This means that if you have a compile-time reference to the fields
>   instead of using the more dynamic fields.getMap() you won't use *any*
>   describe limits.
>
> The limit being on fields.getMap() really means that you can't
>   enumerate fields on more than 100 SObject types in a single
>   transaction. If you use some form of caching ([I have an open source
>   example](https://github.com/capeterson/Apex-Util/blob/master/src/classes/SObjectDescribe.cls)) this is a pretty generous limit.
>
> I actually had to defend this assertion on a code review recently,
>   here's some anonymous apex that can experimentally demonstrate this:

```
List<Schema.SObjectType> objects = new List<Schema.SObjectType>{ Account.SObjectType, Contact.SObjectType, Case.SObjectType, User.SObjectType, Lead.SObjectType};
Integer describes = 0;
while(describes < 500){
    for(Schema.SObjectType objType: objects){
        for(Schema.SObjectField fld: objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
            describes++;
            System.debug('Ran describe ob '+fld.getDescribe().getName());
        }
    }
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Ran a total of '+describes+'field describes');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned that each "getDescribe()" would count against the governor limits.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[]` for multiple sObjects with one [`Schema.describeSObjects()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_System_Schema_describeSObjects) call, but you'll still have to iterate through the results and call [`Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectField_getDescribe) for each field.

Which limit are you concerned about hitting?

Answer (score 3):

You can get all field **Names** for an object using a single describe. But I think not the label. The `DescribeSObjectResult.Fields` map keys give field names suitable for use (eg) in Dynamic SOQL.

**Here's an example using exactly `1` describe to SELECT all fields on an object by `Id`:**

```
static public SObject getById(Id id) {
    SObjectType type = id.getSObjectType();
    DescribeSObjectResult description = type.getDescribe();
    String name = description.getName();
    String fields = String.join(new List<String>(description.fields.getMap().keySet()), ',');
    return Database.query('SELECT ' + fields + ' FROM ' + name + ' WHERE Id = :id');
}
```

If you want the **Label** that strikes me as more of a UI concern. And if you break out into Visualforce, you can do as many`$ObjectType.CustomObject__c.Fields.CustomField__c.Label` as you need. It just isn't so straightforward in Apex.